# Why doesn't compiler complain the variable is redefined?

Tags: c, gcc

I create a simple `test.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;

int a = 100;

void printA(void)
{
        printf("a is %d\n", a);
}
```

Compile it to generate object file:

```
$ gcc -c test.c
$
```

It is OK! But per my understanding, the variable `a` should be redefined, is it right?

Answer (score -1):

A variable is local to block it is defined.Once code in block is executed variable goes out of scope.In your case firstly a is defined globally.In second case it is defined inside a function.Thus, to compiler both a is different in both cases not the same.

Comment: "In second case it is defined inside a function". No it isn't. They are both global.